# Find out where a web part is being used?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there an easy way to find out which sites/pages are using a particular web part in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option would be to write a small tool that iterates over all web sites and pages and checks whether the web part is placed there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your site and page you can find all webparts of page and check if your webpart is there:

```
string AbsolutePageUrl = "http://YourSite/Page.aspx";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(AbsolutePageUrl))
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(AbsolutePageUrl))
   {
     SPLimitedWebPartManager SpWebPartManger = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(AbsolutePageUrl,
     System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);



     foreach (var webpart in SpWebPartManger.WebParts)
     {
          if (webpart is MyWebPart)
             //your web part is here

     }    

   }
}
```

but if you want to check this in all sites you have to find all sites and all pages to check for your webpart Existence